# Index the value of an Enum, not the string

Tags: solr, solrnet

Is it possible to index the value of an Enum instead of its string representation using Solrnet?

Say I have to following enum:

```
[Serializable]
[Flags] 
public enum Gender
{
  Male = 0,
  Female = 1
}
```

and add a solr attribute to the `Gender` property of a `User` class:

```
[SolrField("gender")]
public virtual Gender Gender { get; set; }
```

If I index the entity using:

```
solr.Add(user)
```

then it will index 'Male' as gender instead of 0. Is it possible to have it index 0 instead?

Edit: I'd prefer not to add an extra property for this, like Ondrej proposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by implementing [ISolrFieldSerializer](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/8027e1f589914395cc8c58d55e667c706fd5f8e6/SolrNet/Impl/ISolrFieldSerializer.cs). If the type [IsEnum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isenum.aspx), serialize by casting to int. Otherwise delegate to [DefaultFieldSerializer](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/8027e1f589914395cc8c58d55e667c706fd5f8e6/SolrNet/Impl/FieldSerializers/DefaultFieldSerializer.cs). Use the other [field serializers](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/tree/f5e589ed8751ba1fcff6235021c5d19e39f45fe1/SolrNet/Impl/FieldSerializers) for reference.

Hooking up your field serializer depends on the chosen IoC container, check the container's documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[SolrField("gender")]
public int GenderAsInt
{
    get { return (int) Gender; }
    set { Gender = (Gender) value; }
}

public virtual Gender Gender { get; set; }
```

Also note that declaring your enum as `[Flags]` doesn't make much sense:

- There will hardly be anyone both `Male` and `Female`
- `Male` will be interpreted as the default in respect to the current values of enum fields

Comment: I forgot to mention... preferably without adding extra properties. I have quite a few Enums and I'd be adding around 10 'duplicate' properties.