# Solrnet: unable to retrieve multivalue field from Solr

Tags: c#, solrnet

I have a model similar to below

```
public class Product
{
    [SolrUniqueKey("id")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [SolrField("storage")]
    public string Storage { get; set; }
    [SolrField("components")]
    public Components Components { get; set; }
}

public class Components : List<string>
{
    public Components()
    {}
    public Components(string[] components)
    {
        AddRange(components);
    }
}
```

In my schema.xml I map the fields as:

```
   <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" /> 
   <field name="storage" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true"/>
   <field name="components" type="text_ws" stored="true" multiValued="true" omitNorms="true"/>
```

I've added a list of 5 products to Solr index. If I query from Solr admin page for "*", I get this response doc for one of the results:

```
<doc>
  <arr name="components">
    <str>blah1</str>
    <str>blah2</str>
    <str>blah3</str>
  </arr>
  <str name="id">0</str>
  <str name="storage">foo</str>
</doc>
```

However, when I query Solr via Solrnet using something like:

private readonly ISolrReadOnlyOperations solr
var results = solr.Query(SolrQuery.All);

I find that Components is always null.

Any help is appreciated.

I can see this behaviour for any derived collection.

Comment: I have working multivalue property with `string[]` type (array instead of derived List type).

Comment: @Matej It works for me with string[], however I don't think I can use an array here. The derived List has got reasons for its existence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with a 'proxy' property, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8668330/21239). Or you could write a [ISolrFieldParser](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/c98d65865a7fb4165dada1e15f61e724187cb2c4/SolrNet/Impl/ISolrFieldParser.cs) / [ISolrFieldSerializer](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/8027e1f589914395cc8c58d55e667c706fd5f8e6/SolrNet/Impl/ISolrFieldSerializer.cs) for your Components type.

Independently of this, I agree that separating your domain model from the index model is usually a good idea.

Comment: I did try the proxy property approach where I have a SolrField property that is an array of string and my derived list for my models behaviour. But then I would need to address a different beast - separation of concerns between these two properties. That's when I realized that I shouldn't be bloating my domain model with Indexing specific logic. Thanks for the links to ISolrFieldSerializer. I might need it in another case.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I figured out the reason - when indexed the multivalued entity is stored as an array and when deserialized it gets converted into an ArrayList. Hence, in my case the derived List cannot be used directly.

The lesson learnt is that I need to separate my domain model from my index model - which in retrospect sounds like a good practise.