# How to register a ISolrFieldSerializer in Windsor container so that SolrNet can pick it up

Tags: serialization, solr, castle-windsor, solrnet

I am trying to get an enum to serialize to it's int value when posting to Solr.

So I have implemented a [ISolrFieldSerializer](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/SolrNet/Impl/ISolrFieldSerializer.cs) to do this, As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668275/index-the-value-of-an-enum-not-the-string). But I can seem to register it within the [Windsor](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=MainPage&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) container in a way that it then gets used by SolrNet

Here is what I have:

This works fine apart from the serializer does not get used, although it appears in the containers components list. Any ideas?

```
    container.Register(Component.For<ISolrFieldSerializer>().ImplementedBy<SolrEnumSerializer>());
    Startup.Init<SearchBox>("http://10.10.10.10:0000/solr/boxes");

    container.Register(Component.For<ISolrOperations<SearchBox>>()
                          .UsingFactoryMethod(k => ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<SearchBox>>()));
```

Comment: Try posting on https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/solrnet

Answer (score 3):

I sorted this by removing the default implementation and replace it with a custom one:

```
Startup.Container.Remove<ISolrFieldSerializer>();

var fieldSerializer = new CustomSerializer();
Startup.Container.Register<ISolrFieldSerializer>(c => fieldSerializer);
```

Custom Sertializer:

```
public class CustomSerializer : ISolrFieldSerializer 
    {
        private readonly AggregateFieldSerializer _serializer;

        public CustomSerializer()
        {
            _serializer = new AggregateFieldSerializer(new ISolrFieldSerializer[]
                                                          {
                                                              new MyCustom1Serializer(),
                                                              new MyCustom2Serializer(),
                                                              new CollectionFieldSerializer(this),
                                                              new GenericDictionaryFieldSerializer(this),
                                                              new NullableFieldSerializer(new BoolFieldSerializer()),
                                                              new NullableFieldSerializer(new DateTimeFieldSerializer()),
                                                              //new MoneyFieldSerializer(),
                                                              new FormattableFieldSerializer(),
                                                              new TypeConvertingFieldSerializer(),


                                                          });
        }

        public  bool CanHandleType(Type t)
        {
            return _serializer.CanHandleType(t);
        }

        public IEnumerable<PropertyNode> Serialize(object obj)
        {
            return _serializer.Serialize(obj);
        }
    }
```