# Solr - Scientific notation of double cannot be parsed

Tags: c#, solr, solrnet

For testing, I try to write C#'s Double.MIN (-1.79769313486232E+308) and Double.Max (1.79769313486232E+308) values to a Solr TrieDoubleField by using the library SolrNet. Both double values are send via XML to the Solr server which outputs the following logs:

> 2018-06-06 13:27:46.840 DEBUG (qtp33524623-14) [   x:Test] o.a.s.u.p.AllValuesOrNoneFieldMutatingUpdateProcessor field 'd_DoubleMin' String value '-1.79769313486232E+308' is not mutable, so no values will be mutated
>   2018-06-06 13:27:46.840 DEBUG (qtp33524623-14) [   x:Test] o.a.s.u.p.ParseDoubleFieldUpdateProcessorFactory value '1.79769313486232E+308' is not parseable, thus not mutated; unparsed chars: 'E+308'
>   2018-06-06 13:27:46.840 DEBUG (qtp33524623-14) [   x:Test] o.a.s.u.p.AllValuesOrNoneFieldMutatingUpdateProcessor field 'd_DoubleMax' String value '1.79769313486232E+308' is not mutable, so no values will be mutated

Solrnet uses the scientific notation to pass these double values, but Solr seems to be unable to parse it probably. When I check the content of the added Solr document, both values are set to '-infinity' and 'infinity' respectively.

However, when I write NaN, '-infinity' and 'infinity' to Solr, all values are stored as expected.

I've also checked the Double specification of C# and Solr which seem to be not the same:

- Solr: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_6_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/schema/TrieDoubleField.html
- C#: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/double

Is it a bug of SolrNet or am I missing something?

Comment: Why do you think the double specification of C# and Solr is not same? Both follow IEEE 754.

Comment: It seems to be due to a rounding error. The maximum value of a double is 1.7976931348623157E+308. But SolrNet seems to just use `ToString()` which rounds to 15 digits thus yielding 1.79769313486232E+308 which is larger. They would need to use the roundtrip format when serializing floats/doubles to avoid such errors, i.e. `ToString("R")`. You can check this by comparing the output of `double.MaxValue.ToString()` which yields your value vs. `double.MaxValue.ToString("R")` which yields the "correct" value.

Comment: You are right, the Double.MinValue in C# is -1.7976931348623157E+308.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.minvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you for the hint that the problem might be in the SolrNet library. It seems like that it falls back to the ToStringFieldSerializer and calls the toString() method (https://github.com/SolrNet/SolrNet/blob/9c64895feb4a6da57a49849867ddffe69402ed1c/SolrNet/Impl/FieldSerializers/ToStringFieldSerializer.cs). However, I am still wondering about the Solr logs saying "unparsed chars: 'E+308'"

Comment: It seems to me that the double ranges are not the same because the C# double.MinValue equals -1.7976931348623157E+308 and the Solr's double (which is Java) says that the types minimum value equals 4.9E-324 https://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_6_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/schema/TrieDoubleField.html

However, the C# doc says the types minimum value is about ±5.0 × 10^(−324) which is almost equal. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/double

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, I have implemented an own DoubleFieldSerializer (derived from SolrNets AbstractFieldSerializer). My DoubleFieldSerializer calls obj.ToString("R") in the Parse function instead. I did the same for Float values.

A drawback of my solution is that I need to override the DefaultFieldSerializer to be able to register my FieldSerializers (similar to [Dans solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816795/how-to-register-a-isolrfieldserializer-in-windsor-container-so-that-solrnet-can)).

I've also posted this problem to Github as well. So maybe it will get fixed in the future: https://github.com/SolrNet/SolrNet/issues/422

Comment: One additional point you need to take care of is that the toString() method formats the number according to the applications culture settings.